# Get a variable output to clipboard

Tags: vbscript, pastebin

The idea is that of constructing a URL through a user input, and then getting this output to the pastebin.

So the script runs, asks for a user input which then goes to complete the URL, which in turn gets in the pastebin. At least, that's the idea.

This is the code I've came up with so far:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

dim strLink, defInc, remedy
defInc = "INC"
strLink=InputBox("Enter Incident ID",,defInc)

remedy = "https://1st_part_web_url"& strLink &"%22"

WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /c echo " & remedy & " | clip", 0, TRUE
```

This way I get no output whatsoever to the pastebin. Why not?

Comment: Does your `1st_part_web_url` include any `&`?

Comment: @MC ND: sorry, saw your comment just now. Indeed it does: so what I did was replace the & with %26. Now I get the URL to the pastebin but it doesn't resolve cause the browser still sees the %26 instead of &.
How can I solve this?

Comment: See my answer. No need to escape anything

Comment: To avoid both escaping and shelling out use the method suggested in the second half of my answer.

Comment: @MC ND: your code worked perfectly.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers: couldn't try your option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Dim URL

    URL = "https://somewhere/somePage?var1=something&var2=somethingMore&id=123456789"

    With WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
        .Environment("Process").Item("URL")=URL
        .Run "cmd /c ""(cmd /v:on /c echo(!URL!)|clip"" ", 0, true
    End With
```

To avoid escaping the possible problematic characters in urls, this code uses a environment variable to pass the information to cmd that will pipe the information into clip.exe

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing the command before you run it, and also try running the command visibly:

```
cmd = "cmd.exe /k echo " & remedy & " | clip"
WScript.Echo cmd
WshShell.Run cmd, 1, TRUE
```

Does the command look correct? Do you see an error in the command prompt window?

You could also try an [alternative method](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/08/13/can-i-copy-script-output-to-the-clipboard.aspx) that doesn't require shelling out:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate("about:blank")
ie.document.parentwindow.clipboardData.SetData "text", remedy
ie.Quit
```

Comment: I can execute clip right out of cmd.exe:
`INFO: Type "CLIP /?" for usage.`
 so I think that should not be a problem. Isn't clip Win7 native command?

I cannot just run:
`WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /k echo " & remedy & " | clip", 1, TRUE`
I get a bunch of errors, starting with:
`'WshShell.Run' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @knuckle_sandwich: My bad. `clip.exe` used to be an external command before Windows Vista, but apparently Microsoft has included the functionality since. Fixed. Anyway, you can't run VBScript statements directly from `CMD`. You need to modify the statement in your `.vbs` file the way I suggested and run the script again.

Comment: indeed, I undertood what you mean, and indeed I got my error:
`'server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`
So I guess my variable is getting interpreted, and it shouldn't, correct?
P.S. "server" is part of the URL contained in the remedy variable output

Comment: Got it! Replacing the & with %26 in the URL makes the script work.